# Using Moq with Windsor -- Object of Type Moq.Mock[IFoo] cannot be converted to IFoo

Tags: nunit, castle-windsor, moq

I'm trying to set up some Moq repositories to test my service with Castle Windsor as my IOC.  Mu service depends on IFoo, so I'm creating a moq instance that implements IFoo and injecting it into the container like so:

```
_container.AddComponent("AutoBill", 
  typeof (AutoBillService), typeof (AutoBillService));

var mockUserRepository = new Mock<IUserRepository>();
var testUser = new User()
   {
     FirstName = "TestFirst",
     LastName = "TestLast", 
     UID=1
   };
mockUserRepository.Setup(repo => repo.GetUser(testUser.UID))
   .Returns(testUser);

_container.Kernel.AddComponentInstance("UserRepository", 
   typeof(IUserRepository), mockUserRepository);

var service = _container.Resolve<AutoBillService>(); //FAIL
```

Doing this gives me an exception:
System.ArgumentException: Object of type 'Moq.Mock`1[IUserRepository]' cannot be converted to type 'IUserRepository'

Can anyone see what I'm doing wrong?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You should pass `mockUserRepository.Object` instead of `mockUserRepository`.

This would be a lot more evident if you used the strongly typed API:

```
_container.Register(Component
    .For<IUserRepository>()
    .Instance(mockUserRepository.Object));
```

This compiles because the Object property implements IUserRepository.

Answer (score 1):

I head the same problem with Castle Windsor.
A dinamyc initialization with method:

```
container.Register(Component.For<IUserRepository>()
         .Instance(mockUserRepository.Object));
```

didn't work until I removed from my caslteRepository.config file pre-initialized repositories (like your IUserRepository) and left container "empty" from repositories.